# Failed to copy on "polyfills.js" error in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

Failed to copy while running ionic serve
Failed to copy "polyfills.js" in some specified path??

[image: terminal]

Any Idea??

Comment: while `ng serve` ?

Comment: I was running in Ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running as a regular user and you dont have the correct permissions to the www/build directory.

You need to ensure you run the commands as administrator, on windows you will need to right click the program and select 'Run As Administrator'.

It looks like you are using VS Code on windows if running as administrator does not initiate the Terminal window in the program as administrator then you could try running it in CMD as administrator.

Comment: I tried it agint it cause an error with same problem

Comment: Have you tried to clean the directory manually then re-run the command also?